# Using 'is not' in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to cursor search through some records in an access table from a field called DEV_TYPE. I want to compare each record against a list of know values I have built earlier in my script:

> (devcatList)

I want to print out any values that do not occur in the list. Some of the values in the records are Null as well. I want to set my if statement to only print out values that do not occur in the list, but I also do not want to print out 'None' for the Null values. My script is as follows:

```
if field.name == "DEV_TYPE":
for iRow in arcpy.SearchCursor(fc):
      if not iRow.DEV_TYPE is None or iRow.DEV_TYPE not in devcatList:
          print str(iRow.OBJECTID) + " - " + str(iRow.DEV_TYPE)
```

I've played around with the '`if not x is None`' to '`if x is not None`'. Changed the '`or`' to and '`and`' (even though it was counter intuitive), but my printouts either return all values or no values or only '`None`'....basically everything I don't want. I'm sure I'm doing something silly. Can someone point out what my silliness is?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: I think you want `if iRow.DEV_TYPE is not None and iRow.DEV_TYPE not in devcatList:`

Comment: See, I knew I was doing something silly...and I thought I had tried that. I tested again out of frustration and it works. I must have missed it. Paolo, if you submit this as an answer, I will accept. Thanks,

Comment: Since you care more about inclusion-exclusion tests (`is` and `is not`) I think you might want to consider using a set instead of a list. Which you can easily create with `devcatSet = set(devcatList)`. This would provide O(1) performance instead of O(N).

Comment: for Logic combinations that don't work how you expect, add parens and you can probably get an expected result.  Remove them one by one and you will find where your order of precedence was wrong.  Often leaving extra parens in will improve readability anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want `if iRow.DEV_TYPE is not None and iRow.DEV_TYPE not in devcatList:`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
if field.name == "DEV_TYPE":
    for iRow in arcpy.SearchCursor(fc):
       dev_type = iRow.DEV_TYPE
       if dev_type is not None and dev_type not in devcatList:
           print "{} - {}".format(iRow.OBJECTID, iRow.DEV_TYPE)
```

The `if dev_type is not none` can be more conveniently (but less precisely) stated `if dev_type` since `None` is equivalent to `False` in a conditional context.  I also took the liberty of rewriting the `print` statement in a more idiomatic fashion.

Comment: I would stick with ``dev_type is not None`` since other values (False, 0, etc) can evaluate to False.

Comment: @jterrace Fair point about `is not None` being more precise. Using simple `is dev_type` makes some assumptions that are probably--but not necessarily--true here. Edited be more precise/careful. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jonathon. I tested this as well, and you are right. In my case, this would work as well.

Comment: You might also try `print "{OBJECTID} - {DEV_TYPE}".format(**iRow.__dict__)`. This uses the `**` magic to pass a dict as keywords, plus the `.__dict__` access to the properties of `iRow`. I don't like the amount of magic/internals access required for that, but it makes for a nice, easily comprehended, highly descriptive format string.